# MongoDB Collection Insert Adds _id Field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Simple code to connect to a DB, create a collection, and write a document. However, why is `jsonobj` changed by calling `collection.insert`?

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB', function(err, connection) {
  if (!err) {
    connection.createCollection('test', function (err, collection) {
      if (!err) {
        var jsonobj = {foo: 'bar', abc: 'xyz'};
        collection.insert(jsonobj, function (err, result) {
          if (!err) {
            //is not equal to the previous value of jsonobj
            console.log(jsonobj); 
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The output I get is `{ foo: 'bar', abc: 'xyz', _id: 5769a38cd01e25512a3dbdd8 }`, which is not equal to the original value of `jsonobj`. I understand that MongoDB documents all have an `_id` field, but why is it added to my object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/

> _id
>
> A field required in every MongoDB document. The _id field must have a unique value. You can think of the _id field as the document’s
>   primary key. If you create a new document without an _id field,
>   MongoDB automatically creates the field and assigns a unique BSON
>   ObjectId.

Your object IS the document and so Mongo adds it.

Comment: Why would modifying the object be useful?

Comment: Well it uniquely identifies the document so even if you had two documents with the exact same fields they would be able to be differentiated.

Comment: I mean, in what use case would a developer find it useful to have his object modified?

Comment: As far as I know that is the only modification done by Mongo to your document. It is useful to a developer because it is a unique value that you can store and update and query by. For instance, if you were going to list contact information (and let's say a contact has 40 fields) but you only wanted to show first name and last name. You could bring down the entire object, get a has and store that to keep track of which John Doe the user picked. you could also just utilize the guaranteed unique object id and just send down the those three fields (first, last and _id).

Comment: If you do an Insert operation with myObj, then try to do a Replace operation using the same myObj, it will fail because the myObj now has an (inmutable) _id field. It took me a while to realize what was happening. Mutating the user's objects is a terrible practice. And the quote you provide is completely unclear, I see it meaning the _id is added to the database object, not my node.js object.